# Odd error using intrinsic typecasting in CUDA

Tags: c++, casting, cuda

I cannot figure out what the difference between the following pieces of code is:

```
int t = __double2int_rd(pos.x/params.cellSize.x*2.0)&1;
if( t ==0) {...}
```

and

```
if(__double2int_rd(pos.x/params.cellSize.x*2.0)&1 == 0) {...}
```

The second option never returns true, while the first behaves as expected.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second expression first evaluates `(1==0)` whose result is always false. Then `ANDs` it with the result of the function `__double2int_rd`.

Therefore it actually evaluates:

`if(__double2int_rd(pos.x/params.cellSize.x*2.0) & 0)`

Which would always be false.

The equivalent of the first expression would be:

`if((__double2int_rd(pos.x/params.cellSize.x*2.0) & 1) == 0)`

Mind the brackets.
Its a good programming practice to add brackets if you are not sure about the order of evaluation of expressions.

Comment: Thank you! It absolutely didn't occur to me that == has higher precedence than &.

Comment: First time asking on stack overflow - sorry about the delay in accepting. I asked this Q because I was dead scared that intrinsic functions might be behaving in some odd manner. Of course it makes sense that logical AND and bitwise AND are exactly the same thing thing - silly of me!